# Calling a function inside a jquery click event

Tags: jquery

I am trying to call a function inside a `click` event with jQuery, but jQuery returns `undefined` when the function is called. What is the correct way to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#my_button').click(function() {
      var valid = check(something);
      if (valid) { // do something }
   });

   check = function(param) {
     .ajax {
         // ajax params
         success: function(data) { 
            if (data)
               return true;
         }
     }
   }
});
```

if you do a `console.log(valid)`, it is returned as `undefined`

**UPDATE**: I've added the code inside `check()`, which is an ajax call. That seems to be the problem. If I just do an `alert()` inside check, then everything works. So what's wrong with the ajax call?

Comment: Unable to reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/ZQxRv/, maybe you should show the commented out code.

Comment: Could it be because something is undefined? ;-)

Comment: Updated the question to make it more clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Musa it works when I'm just calling an alert inside the check function. However, if I run an ajax call, then it goes back to "undefined".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is check is an asynchronous event. You need to use a callback instead of a return statement:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#my_button').click(function() {
      check(something, function (valid) {
         if (valid) { // do something }
      });
   });

   check = function(param, callback) {
     $.ajax({
        // ajax params
        success: function(data) { 
            if (data){
               return callback(true);
            }
            else {
               return callback(false);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
function check(param)
{
    //do something
    return true;
}
```

Then you can call check from wherever in your Javascript code.

Let me add that I thought this way was best since I do not like using function pointers unless there is a reason. There does not appear to be one in this case.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `var` before `check`

```
var check = function(param) {
 // do something
 return true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

That is because `check` needs to be declared above the jquery click event I believe. Try this:

```
var check = function(param) {
 // do something
 return true;
}

$('#my_button').click(function() {
  var valid = check(something);
  if (valid) { // do something }
});
```